# Output file is only showing last line of the input file

Tags: java, file-io

In the output file "CMFTSwitchesnew.txt" only has the last line of the input file. I've tested a few different methods such as changing write.println(input.nextLine()) but I'm not sure now where the issue is.

```
package WorkingWithFiles;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileIO
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        File output = new File("CMFTSwitchesNew.txt");
        File source = new File("src/CMFTSwitches.txt");

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(source);

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {

                try {

                    PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(output);
                    String text = input.nextLine();
                    write.println(text) // also tried 
                                        // write.println(input.nextLine());
                    write.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.out.println("Exception found");
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("The file was not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           try {

                PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(output);
                String text = input.nextLine();
                write.println(text) // also tried 
                                    // write.println(input.nextLine());
                write.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Exception found");
            }
```

You're creating a PrintWriter in each iteration without using the constructor that allows you to tell the `PrintWriter` to append data at the end of an already existing file. That way you only see the output of the last time the file was written. Either change that to

```
PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(output, true);
```

or instantiate the `PrintWriter` outside the `while`-loop and close it after it.

Comment: Easy when you know how! All working now. Needed to close input as well which I'd forgotten to do.
Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. You might accept this answer, though ;-)